# Transaction-safe, replication-safe way to duplicate rows with primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm using InnoDB tables in MySQL. Application is in PHP, but ideally this would all be done via queries. I have several tables with typical integer auto_increment primary keys. Sometimes I need to duplicate rows, but I can't do this without new primary key values. This would be trivial if I hard-code lists of columns in the queries, but I want to avoid that. I wrote code to use temporary tables so I can get rid of the existing primary key values before inserting, but apparently that isn't replication-safe (and the MySQL 5.1 docs are inconsistent about what queries might cause an implicit commit when using temporary tables).

I basically want the conceptual opposite of `INSERT IGNORE`. Rather than update existing rows, I want a new primary key value. Is there a reasonable way to do this without hard-coding lists of columns?

**Edit:** I should clarify that the primary key isn't going to be the only column that needs modification. There would typically be one more that refers to the ID for a different record type. The overall goal is to duplicate an existing record and attach it to a different parent record. My impulse is to duplicate the record, then make any other updates in a second query.

Comment: What is your use case for why you want 100% duplicate rows?  Doing this, you break the benefits of a primary key--generally a very bad thing to do.  Tables don't need PK's, so you could just remove the key.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks, see edit to original question